# having difficulties with c# to Json

Tags: c#, json, type-conversion

i am quite new to Json, i have a program which makes a put request with some json data.

i need to make the equivelant of this: `{ "project": { "date_closed":"2017-01-05"} }`

and this is my code i need to adapt..

```
object instructionData = new { date_closed = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") };

var instructionString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instructionData);
StringContent instruction = new StringContent(instructionString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

which is currently more than i can seem to figure out...

i've looked at some converters, which just creates classes. And those i don't really know what to do with..

Hope there is someone willing to help.

**Edit**
i am creating a response which is being sent.

```
var response = instructions.GetPutResponse(instructions.GetCleanUpProjectsRequestUrl(projectId), instructions.GetJsonInstructions(instructionData), client);
```

GetPutResponse method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetPutResponse(string requestUrl, HttpContent httpContent, HttpClient client)
    {
        return client.PutAsync(requestUrl, httpContent).Result;
    }
```

Comment: `instructionData ` is an anonymous object - or is this meant to be the JSON that is included in the 'put' request?

Comment: the instruction is included in the put request.

Comment: can you show more of your code - is this a controller method? please edit your question to show the full method

Comment: For such simple JSON it seems like overkill to use classes and JSONConvert. Can't you simply concatenate strings to create that JSON? `var json = "{\"project\": { \"date_closed\":\"" + date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "\"} }";`;

Comment: it is part of a bigger program, which reuses alot of code.  but inserting that @Equalsk gives me errors, invalid anonymous member type declarator, must be declared with member assignment, simple name or member access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Project
{
    public string date_closed { get; set;}
}

public class MyClass
{
    public Project project { get; set;}
}

var obj = new MyClass();
obj.project = new Project();
obj.project.date_closed = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

var instructionString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Comment: this did indeed solve the initial problem. though would have hoped for something a bit less extensive. But that is for me to keep working on. Thx for the solution ^^

Answer (score 1):

Like one of comments above suggests using string concatenation which seems fair approach however if you don't want to go that route then you can use following snippet to achieve what you want. Replace below line

```
object instructionData = new { date_closed = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") };
```

with

```
var instructionData = new { projects = new { date_closed = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") } };
```

Comment: it generates this: { projects = {{ date_closed = 2017-01-05 }} }   which seems to return a bad request.. do you know why it generates double brackets around the date ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing differently however output of serialization i.e. value of instructionString should be { "project": { "date_closed":"2017-01-05"} }. I tested it and produces correct string.

Comment: i inserted the exact same thing, but it generates double brackets... that is really wierd..